# Kaomoji bar is broken in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, unicode, emoji, emoji-keyboard

If I use the emoji/kaomoji/symbol bar in windows 10, the bottom sections of the kaomoji bar are broken.

Image of Broken Kamoji bar:

[image: Image of Broken Kamoji bar]

See, the bottom of the bar is only showing squares, not descriptions.
My OS is windows 10 version 2004 Build 19041.572.
Can someone please provide a solution to this?

Comment: @DanielB It's not a problem with emojis. They work perfectly fine on my computer. It's just that the kamoji section only shows these weird squares.

Comment: Okay, so having tried on multiple Windows 10 machines I can confirm this simply broken. I don’t think there’s a way to fix this as a user.