# Windows 10 Kaomoji panel categories have missing icons

Tags: windows-10, icons

I'm using Windows 10 20H2 en-US x64 (19042.572, fully updated). When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to bring up the Emoji/Kaomoji/Symbols panel, on the Kaomoji 'tab' the category icons at the bottom are missing and only boxes are displayed as you can see below:

[image: Missing category icons in Windows 10 Kaomoji panel]

Looks like a possible font issue, but how do I fix it?

(I tried a web search but the [only mention on MS Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-kaomoji-categories-have-missing-icons/d0f32b72-c774-4c53-8df4-e227a22b3ce8) lacks a useful answer.)

Comment: Someone please create the **windows-10-v20h2** tag! :)

Comment: duplicate: [Kaomoji bar is broken in windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1598485/241386)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the icon display in windows 10 20H2. The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run in to while using Windows 10. You can report this issue to Microsoft directly with the Feedback Hub app.
For more information on using the app, click here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332